# Simplifying IF statement logic - inner logic overlap

Tags: c#

Can the below logical if conditions be simplified ?
I have wrote this code but some parts are overlapping so I thought to seek for some help to see whether it can be simplified...

I have actually three different fields but following the same patterns.

EDIT :

```
    if (Row.ReceivableAmount_IsNull == true && Row.CustomerID == LastCustomerID)
    {
        if (LastReceivableAmount == null)
        {
            Row.PreviousReceivableAmount_IsNull = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Row.PreviousReceivableAmount = LastReceivableAmount.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Row.PreviousReceivableAmount = LastReceivableAmount.GetValueOrDefault();
        LastReceivableAmount = Row.ReceivableAmount;
    }

    if (Row.SaleAmount_IsNull == true && Row.CustomerID == LastCustomerID)
    {
        if (LastSaleDate == null)
        {
            Row.PreviousSaleDate_IsNull = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Row.PreviousSaleDate = LastSaleDate.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (LastSaleDate == null)
        {
            Row.PreviousSaleDate_IsNull = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Row.PreviousSaleDate = LastSaleDate.GetValueOrDefault();
        }

        LastSaleDate = Row.Date;
    }

    if (Row.PaymentAmount_IsNull == true && Row.CustomerID == LastCustomerID)
    {
        if (LastPaymentDate == null)
        {
            Row.PreviousPaymentDate_IsNull = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Row.PreviousPaymentDate = LastPaymentDate.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Row.PreviousPaymentDate = LastPaymentDate.GetValueOrDefault();
        LastPaymentDate = Row.Date;
    }
```

Comment: `Row.SaleAmount_IsNull == true` can be simplified to `Row.SaleAmount_IsNull`

Comment: Same goes for `Row.ReceivableAmount_IsNull == true` and `Row.PaymentAmount_IsNull == true`

Comment: resharper can suggest you this things. its a good extension for .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you only care about LastSaleDate in your outer if condition, so move everything else out.

Once you've moved it out, you can invert your original condition, reducing your if/else to just an if.

```
if (LastReceivableAmount == null)
{
    Row.PreviousReceivableAmount_IsNull = true;
}
else
{
    Row.PreviousReceivableAmount = LastReceivableAmount.GetValueOrDefault();
}
if (!Row.ReceivableAmount_IsNull || Row.CustomerID != LastCustomerID)
{
    Row.PreviousReceivableAmount = LastReceivableAmount.GetValueOrDefault();
    LastReceivableAmount = Row.ReceivableAmount;
}


if (LastSaleDate == null)
{
    Row.PreviousSaleDate_IsNull = true;
}
else
{
    Row.PreviousSaleDate = LastSaleDate.GetValueOrDefault();
}
if (!Row.SaleAmount_IsNull || Row.CustomerID != LastCustomerID)
{
    LastSaleDate = Row.Date;
}   


if (LastPaymentDate == null)
{
    Row.PreviousPaymentDate_IsNull = true;
}
else
{
    Row.PreviousPaymentDate = LastPaymentDate.GetValueOrDefault();
}
if (!Row.PaymentAmount_IsNull == true || Row.CustomerID != LastCustomerID)
{
    Row.PreviousPaymentDate = LastPaymentDate.GetValueOrDefault();
    LastPaymentDate = Row.Date; 
}
```

Comment: why do you invert the second `if`? is there any benefit ? just want to know

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary There is an accepted style standard that as few nested conditions as possible is the most readable way in which to write code.  By inverting the condition, we are able to reduce our if/else to a single if, preventing potential nested checks down the road.

Comment: @David L at least i can use your code to replace each part ..? Sure it will be simpler than whats now.

Comment: @superted fair enough.  I've updated my answer to fit your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Since both branches of the `if` are similar, except one statement, you could use the following approach:

```
if (LastSaleDate == null)
{
    Row.PreviousSaleDate_IsNull = true;
}
else
{
    Row.PreviousSaleDate = LastSaleDate.GetValueOrDefault();
}

if (!Row.SaleAmount_IsNull || Row.CustomerID != LastCustomerID)
{
    LastSaleDate = Row.Date;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code .. is it possible to simplify updated codes?